# Role of TimeOut and time passed to Await.result

Tags: akka

I have a akka actor service running on 127.0.0.1:2552.

I am trying to access it from a client, like this:

```
val client = new SClient("127.0.0.1:2552")
describe("akkaDbClient") {
it("should set a value"){
  client.set("123", new Integer(123))
  val futureResult = client.get("123")
  val result = Await.result(futureResult, 10 seconds)
  result should equal(123)
 }
}

class SClient(remoteAddress: String){
private implicit val timeout = Timeout(2000)
private implicit val system = ActorSystem("LocalSystem")
private val remoteDb = 
   system.actorSelection(s"akka.tcp://akkadb@$remoteAddress/user/akka-db")

def set(key: String, value: Object) = {
 remoteDb ? SetRequest(key, value)
}

def get(key: String) = {
  remoteDb ? GetRequest(key)
 }
}
```

I am not able to understand the role of TimeOut and time argument passed to Await.result().

What do these values signify, and how do they impact the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Future is executed in the background and not on the main thread. It is possible, if there is heavy computation, that it takes very long. Or worse if there is an infinite loop and the future never returns.

This is not a problem (in a pragmatic sense) until you wait for it to complete. It would block the execution just like a normal infinite loop would. So you can specify a timeout for how long you intend to wait for a result before it stops with a `TimeoutException`.

If `client.get(123)` takes longer than 10 seconds you will get an Exception and the test will fail. Otherwise it would never return and run until you kill the process manually.

[More reading about Futures](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

Concerning the second timeout: You are asking your actor for a future with a possible response. This could also time out.

In your particular example, the timeout will occur if your actor takes longer than two seconds. But if you for instance mapped, flatmapped, filtered the future and then returned it, those operations would time out after ten seconds.

```scala
implicit val timeout = Timeout(2000)

val f1 = actor ? message // timout of 2 seconds
val f2 = f1 map longRunningOperation

Await.result(f2, 10 seconds) // timeout of 10 seconds
```

Comment: There are 2 time values in my code. 2000 and 10. As you said, 10 is the waiting period for future to be calculated. What about value 2000?Its passed implicitly to send request.